# Cypher Determine if Paths exist to Shared Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a sample graph as depicted below.

[image]
The nodes have the following labels:

- node (a) has label `User`
- nodes (b) until (g) have label `Attribute`
- nodes (h) and (i) have label `Object`

Node (a) has a relationship to (d) and also to (e)

I want to check which of the `Object` nodes (h) and (i) have relationships to *all* of the `Attribute` nodes that the user is connected to, i.e. (d) and (e).

So

- node (h) has a relationship to (d) AND to (e) -->  this is ok
- node (i) only has a relationship to (e) --> this is not ok

How would I detect this in a Cypher query?

I started with something like:

```
MATCH p1 = (u:User)-->(ua:Attribute)-->(oa:Attribute)
WITH *
MATCH p2 = (oa)<-[*]-(o:Object)
RETURN p1,p2
```

This gives me the complete graph. But how do I refine this to get only (h) back and not (i).

I guess I will have to build a list of results from the first part and validate if a relation exist to all of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this with the `ALL` predicate :

```
// First retrieve the Attribute nodes the User is connected to and make it a collection
MATCH (u:User)-[:ASSOCIATED_TO]->(attribute)
WITH u, collect(attribute) AS attributes
// Find the objects having relationships to ALL elements in attributes
MATCH (o:Object) WHERE 
ALL( x IN attributes WHERE (o)--(x) )
RETURN u, attributes, collect(o) AS objects
```

Comment: Hi, thanks !!, this seems to do the job.. i slightly adapted the query syntax to match the sample  graph layout but the following code worked :MATCH (u:User)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(ua:Attribute)-[:ASSOCIATED_TO]->(oa:Attribute)
WITH u, COLLECT(oa) AS Attributes
MATCH (o:Object) WHERE 
ALL( x IN Attributes WHERE (o)-[*]->(x) )
RETURN u, COLLECT(o) AS Objects